# clip and display result in same time

Tags: powershell

How can I use `clip` and display output at the same time?

Every time if I put `| clip` at the of the end line, the output is copied to clipboard, but not displayed in the console window.

```
Get-Date | clip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into this a bit I think the only way to do what you're asking is to do it in two separate lines.

```
$value = Get-Date
Write-host $value
$value | clip
```

One line would look like this `$value = Get-Date;$value;$value|clip`

Powershell really wants to redirect anything from write-host to the console. And clip doesn't want to pass anything further down the pipeline...

Answer (score 6):

Use **common parameter `-ov` (`-OutVariable`)** to also capture `Get-Date`'s output in a *variable*, then output that variable:

```
Get-Date -ov output | clip; $output
```

If the command you're invoking is not a cmdlet or advanced function/script and therefore doesn't support `-OutVariable`, you can use this technique instead:

```
($output = Get-Date) | clip; $output
```

This relies on the fact that enclosing a variable assignment in `(...)` passes the assigned value through.

---

You can **package this functionality** with the help of a custom function:

```
Function Write-OutputAndClip { $Input | Write-Output -ov output | clip; $output }
```

If you also define an alias for it, say `clipecho` ...

```
Set-Alias clipecho Write-OutputAndClip
```

... you can invoke it succinctly as:

```
Get-Date | clipecho  # copies output to the clipboard *and* echoes it.
```